# Table Join in JPA - Creating an entity that contains Join

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entities, join

I have an entity called "Person". Its joined by table `pers_addr_tb` to `Address` entity.
So the Person entity looks like this

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "pers_addr_tb", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pers_ID"), 
                           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "addr_ID"))
public List<Address> addresses;
```

Now lets say I create the Person first and then some Address entities.
What happens if pers_addr_tb does not exist? Is it created when Person and Address are created?

For testing, we are using in-memory HSQL db (with OpenEJB). So we need to create the entities on the fly as needed.
But pers_addr_tb is not defined as entity.

Comment: Are the tables don't exist in the database and you want to generate them with the metadata?

Comment: @PaulVargas, yes. Thats right. These tables don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You create a Person instance and persist it. JPA inserts a row in the person table.

Then you create an Address instance and persist it. JPA inserts a row in the address table.

Then you add the address to the list of addresses of the person, and Hibernate inserts a row in the join table.

This is in fact partially true, because the inserts will in fact be done when you commit the transaction. But the principle of an ORM like JPA is that the mapping you specify in the entities tell JPA how and where the entities and their associations must be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) is bundled with [OpenEJB](http://tomee.apache.org/) as the default persistence provider. For details regarding the annotation `@JoinTable`, see the [manual](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual/main.html) in [8.5.  Join Table](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_field.html#jpa_overview_mapping_assoccoll)

If there is no error in the mapping annotations, once loaded OpenJPA, this may generate or modify the tables automatically in the database. You need to add in the `persistence.xml` the next property:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" 
          value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
```

For more details about this, see the section [1.3. Runtime Forward Mapping](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual/ref_guide_mapping.html#ref_guide_mapping_synch) in the the [manual](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual/main.html).